# How stagger vertical classes/boxes in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a instant messaging system between two people coded in python/django using some html/css. Right now the sender and receiver have chat boxes that stack on top of each other. I want to stagger them so that there is white space to the left of the sender's box and white space to the right of the receiver's box (kinda like a looking a vertical strip on a brick wall). If I can stagger one, I can stagger both so I'll just show the code for one to keep it simple.
HTML

[image]

I'm not sure if I need to adjust the padding or justificaiton or something else.

```
<div class="textcontainer">
    {{ message }}
    <span class="time-right">{{ message.timestamp }}</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.textcontainer {
border: 2px solid #dedede;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px 0;
}
.textcontainer::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you add a screenshot how it is showing up now and how you want it to look.

Comment: With flex it would probally workout nicely: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I added a screen shot. Thanks, I'll start looking at flex.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good ol' `margin-left: 50px;` `margin-right: 50px;` will do the trick. Thanks for letting me humor y'all.